# Authenticate Firestore without Firebase JSON File?

Tags: firebase, api, asp.net-core, .net-core, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an application that connects to a Database from Firestore, and when looking into the documentation the way they recommend for authentication into firestor is using the Firebase JSON file, for example this my adapter's constructor code:

```
 public UserDataAdapter()
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS","//file_path");
        _firestoreDb = FirestoreDb.Create("databaseName") ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(FirestoreDb));
        
    }
```

This is the source I am using: https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Firestore/latest.

So is there a way that I could authenticate Firestore without using the JSON file?

In the past I used the library for Firebase Authentication called FirebaseAuthentication.net and it uses something like this:

```
var auth = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(_firebaseSettings.ApiKey));
```

In where the ApiKey is the firebase secret, I am trying to do something like that

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
var GoogleSecretJson = builder.Configuration["GoogleSecretJson"];
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(GoogleSecretJson).CreateScoped();
var firestoreClientBuilder = new FirestoreClientBuilder
{
    ChannelCredentials = credential.ToChannelCredentials()
};
var client = firestoreClientBuilder.Build();
var db = FirestoreDb.Create("firestore-db", client: client);
```

You can set the `GoogleSecretJson` value from JSON file content.

Comment: Hello @Anuraj, your code stills requires the Google Auth JSON file